# JQuery radio buttons of same name and value - show hidden div when radio button clicked on | Ecwid

Tags: jquery, radio-button

I am using Ecwid shopping cart and want to hide/show some options in a product based on if a radio button is checked.

My test product is here:

http://www.farmboutique.com/testproduct1.html#!/~/product/category=5128132&id=21349373

I have hidden some of the selections on loading the page using javascript.

Now I want to show the hidden selections when somebody clicks on the radio button for:

> Yes (no more than 9cm x 9cm) (+£4.50)

under the option "Do You Require An Embroidered Logo".

The default value "Not required" is always selected upon loading of the page.

Likewise if somebody clicks on the Yes option after the page has loaded and then change their mind by selecting "Not Required", it should make the other options disappear again.

The html code for the radio buttons for "Yes (no more than 9cm x 9cm) (+£4.50)" and "Not Required" is:

```
    <div id="ecwid-productoption-21349373-Do_You_Require_An_Embroidered_Logo-container" class="ecwid-productBrowser-details-optionPanel ecwid-productBrowser-details-optionPanel-radio ecwid-productoption-Do_You_Require_An_Embroidered_Logo-container">

    <label class="ecwid-fieldLabel" for="gwt-uid-5">Do You Require An Embroidere​d Logo</label>

    <div id="gwt-uid-5"><span class="gwt-RadioButton ecwid-productBrowser-details-optionRadioButton ecwid-productoption-Do_You_Require_An_Embroidered_Logo-Yes_:0028no_more_than_9cm_x_9cm:0029" id="ecwid-productoption-21349373-Do_You_Require_An_Embroidered_Logo-Yes_:0028no_more_than_9cm_x_9cm:0029">

    <input type="radio" name="21349373-Do You Require An Embroidered Logo" value="on" id="gwt-uid-3" tabindex="0">

    <label for="gwt-uid-3"><span class="ecwid-productBrowser-details-optionRadioButton-name">Yes (no more than 9cm x 9cm)</span>

    <span class="ecwid-productBrowser-details-optionRadioButton-price"> <span class="ecwid-productBrowser-details-optionRadioButton-bracket">(</span>

    <span class="ecwid-productBrowser-details-optionRadioButton-sign">+</span>

    <span>£</span>4.50<span class="ecwid-productBrowser-details-optionRadioButton-bracket">)</span></span></label></span>

    <span class="gwt-RadioButton ecwid-productBrowser-details-optionRadioButton ecwid-productoption-Do_You_Require_An_Embroidered_Logo-Not_Required" id="ecwid-productoption-21349373-Do_You_Require_An_Embroidered_Logo-Not_Required">

<input type="radio" name="21349373-Do You Require An Embroidered Logo" value="on" id="gwt-uid-4" tabindex="0" checked="">

<label for="gwt-uid-4"><span class="ecwid-productBrowser-details-optionRadioButton-name">Not Required</span></label></span></div></div>
```

21349373 in the above is the product Id = page.productId

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do it this way. The main issue is that I could not found any valid selector to target your radio button because there are spaces in it's name and I could not be sure the generated `id` would not change. Try adding some static attributes on your elements so that it's easier to query them. If you have no control over the `id` and `name` attributes, you can add some other custom attributes.

```
$(function () {
    //get a reference to your hidden div
    var $divIfRequired = $('[id*=If_you_require_a_logo_to_be]');

    //add a click handler on your radio button
    $('put_some_selector_here').click(function () {
        //show or hide the div based on the checked status of the radio button
        $divIfRequired[this.checked? 'show': 'hide']();
    });
});
```